# Свойство version в Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Наткнулся на [такой момент](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%20version%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

> Свойство верхнего уровня version определяется спецификацией Compose для обеспечения обратной совместимости. Это только информативно.

> Compose не использует version выбор точной схемы для проверки файла
> Compose, а предпочитает самую последнюю схему при ее реализации.

Верно ли я понимаю, что Compose вообще по барабану какую тут версию указывать и он все равно запустит с самой последней?

Например я напишу:

```
version: '2'
```

или

```
version: '2.3'
```

Он все равно запустит под версией 3.8, т.к. эта самая актуальная на данный момент.

Comment: Это версия спецификации. Как максимум, compose может отказаться включать фичи, которые не соответствуют номеру спецификации. В любом случае, запускать будет тот плагин, который установлен в вашей системе. Если установлен 3.8, значит, 3.8.